# Can I edit the iOS limit ad tracking setting from an (native) app?

Tags: ios, iphone

From a (native) iOS app, is it possible to change this setting?

IOS > settings > privacy > advertising > limit ad tracking (on/off)

To turn on limit ad tracking automatically?

If this is not possible can I request the status so I know if I have to change it manually?